# scalatra issue when running ./sbt: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.1.1: not found

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatra

I tried adding eclipse support to my project by running `./sbt eclipse` after adding `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.1")` to `project/plugins.sbt`.

I get this error message

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.1.1: not found
```

I created the project by g8 using the simplest template. I'm trying to add eclipse support

[Edit: sbt version]

```
Detected sbt version 0.13.0
Starting sbt: invoke with -help for other options
Using /Users/andre/.sbt/0.13.0 as sbt dir, -sbt-dir to override.
```

Comment: Please add the sbt version you are using in your question. The right version of the plugin depends on the version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of sbt are you using? [typesafehub/sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) says the latest is 2.3.0 for sbt 0.13, and 2.2.0 for sbt 0.12.

Comment: Try sbteclipse-plugin 2.3.0 then.

Comment: ```addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.3.0")``` worked.